# Change the PDF content and custom annotations color for existing PDF using iText

Tags: pdf, itext

The problem now we are facing is- We are loading some color Eng. graphics and doing annotation.
All looks fine and working well and good. Now, at the end of job completion we need to print the PDF file with annotation in black and white. 
Here, since the PDF is colored one, we are not able to see print clearly.

**Is there any option to make all content in PDF to black color later**? So that print will be very clear.

Like [this problem](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2006/01/converting_colo/).

Comment: It's not something that can be done "out-of-the-box". I'm not saying it's impossible, but it would be a lot of work, kind of building a new product. So the safe answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Masi, Thanks for response. I am hoping same. I wanted to check with company like itext and qoppa. hope they have some option and idea.

Comment: iText does not expose high level APIs for content editing. It does contain, though, a low level API on which one can build that functionality. The itext-extra artifact contains an OCG remover which uses the same low level API for some content editing, so you might want to take it as an example: [OCGParser](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGParser.java) actually edits page content streams, [OCGRemover](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/trunk/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGRemover.java) uses OCGParser and does some extras